# There's difference between "$var === true" and "true === $var"?

Tags: javascript

A few time ago, I saw in a JavaScript application (I don't remember which one is) the use of `true === $var` instead of `$var === true`. Example:

```
if (true === $var) {
    // do something
}
```

I think these comparisons are differnet but I can see why — someone can explain it for me? And plus: when I should use and when I shouldn't.

### Duplicated?

I searched on the web but no results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference between them.

Yoda comparisons are done by some people to prevent a typo (missing `=`s) creating an assignment instead of a comparison (since `true = $var` will throw an error while `$var = true` will not).

Comment: [Reference for yoda conditions](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/07/new-programming-jargon.html) :)

Comment: Yoda Comparison is the name? LOL! By the way, very clarifying. Thank you!

Comment: My fav is *Refuctoring* BTW

Answer (score 1):

I think this is just a best practice kind of thing, at least I'm used to seeing the suggestion when coding in languages such as C#, where it's easy to accidentally do

```
if(someVar = 1)
```

instead of:

```
if(someVar == 1)
```

Doing it in reverse prevents that possibility, as the compiler will pick up the fact that you can't assign the value of a variable to a literal (or constant, if you use constants).

Answer (score 0):

**No** there is not any difference in both

But there is difference in $var == false and $var === false

```
$var = 0;
$var == false // TRUE
$var === false // FALSE
```

=== will also compare the variable type. It checks if it's a bool, string or integer for example.

```
$var = "1";

$var == 1 // TRUE
$var === 1 // FALSE
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? Whilst the answer does not describe the Yoda comparison pattern in the other answers, it is factually correct in stating that comparatively the operations are equivalent - as stated by the most voted answer. The OP probably knows about the difference in equality checking between == and === as the latter is used in the question, but this is also useful information for beginners. I can understand not upvoting, but a downvote seems a bit harsh.

Comment: @pwdst The information is useful and I'm neutral (I don't downvoted the question), but if you think a little better, there's something wrong on its essence: the question is not about the operators and that's why I think that our buddy Avneesh received some downvotes.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge The first line of the answer does address the question - the additional information is just that, additional. Whilst the answer could certainly do with being expanded upon, it is not wrong.

Comment: Hmmm, you're right. I read again and you win, hehe. Thanks!